# Coverage reports not being processed by codecov anymore

Tags: python, code-coverage, codecov

I had setup `codecov` with `gitlab` pipelines a while back and was able to see coverage reports in `codecov`. Since the initial setup the reports stopped processing after a few commits, and I have not been able to figure out what I'm doing wrong to get the reports processing again.

In `gitlab` pipelines I use `tox` and `pip install codecov`:

```
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - pip install circuitpython-build-tools Sphinx sphinx-rtd-theme tox codecov
    - tox
    - codecov -t $CODECOV_TOKEN
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - htmlcov/
```

In `tox` I run `coverage`:

```
[testenv:coverage]
deps = -rrequirements.txt
       -rtest-requirements.txt
commands = coverage run -m unittest discover tests/
           coverage html
```

In `codecov` I can see where the upload attempts to process, but it fails without much description:

```
There was an error processing coverage reports.
```

I've referenced the python tutorials, but can't see what I'm getting wrong.

https://github.com/codecov/codecov-python

https://github.com/codecov/example-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like maybe this was something on the `codecov.io` side. I didn't change anything, but came into coverage reports parsing and the badge working again this morning.